# Nullpointer on new activity wizard

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, wizard

I'm studying Android through the Udacity. I'm on the Intents Lesson, "Exercise: Create an Activity" and one of the part of the Lesson is to create a new Activity using the wizard of Android Studio.

What happens is: I go to the New > Activity > Empty Activty and then the ugly Null Pointer appears.

"Exception in plugin Android Support. Moments ago. Ocurred 5 times since the last clear. Unread. Disable plugin".

What I've already tried:

- Changing buildToolsVersion
- Installing Android Studio 2.3 Beta (I'm on the latest stable version: 2.2)
- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Importing another project
- Checked my JAVA_HOME (1.8.0_92-b14)
- Reported the problem to Google
- Disabled the plugin (when I did that, showed a lot of errors, so I rolled back the change)

None of these solved my problem. Can anyone help me?

The stacktrace:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed(NewAndroidComponentAction.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:312)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Have you tried making the Activity by hand?  All you have to do is create a new class that extends Activity, and add the activity to the manifest.  I don't think I've ever actually used the menu to create an Activity.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But, for convenience, I'd like to let the wizard working.

Comment: I had the same problem. Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947592/4137250), it resolved my problem.