# Error while creating new Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a new Activity, but the following error comes up (bottom of image)

> InvalidReferenceException: Error executing FreeMarker template...

If I manually create an Activity by creating a Java Class which extends the Activity Class, then it works.

[image]

Comment: You could add the Activity class and the XML layout file manually instead of using the wizard. Remember to add it to the Manifest.

Comment: Think about it this way... File > New > Java class and doing it from scratch helps you learn better :)

Comment: Yeah I know that, I am using that way only. But I was wondering what is the error which I am getting and how to correct it.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the template engine that creates the auto-generated code. (Look at the bottom toolbar). Not sure what can be done to "fix" it, though, without reinstalling stuff.

Comment: If the problem is with the auto-generated code from the wizard, then this problem can be averted (hopefully) by adding your stuff manually. Right-click on the package you want your new Activity to reside in, choose New -> Java Class, give it a name, and make sure you extend AppCompatActivity. Once created, override your onCreate method, create the XML layout file and add the Activity to the Manifest. This is the proper way to do things, IMO.

Comment: If the cause is the same as in the following discussion, you may have to get rid of C:\tmp if it has been created : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232076

Comment: Yeah @mwieczorek I am doing things the way you described. But I wanted to know what is causing the error and how to correct it.

Comment: Thanks @Berger deleting the tmp folder helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the following link : [Cannot create empty activity, in Android Studio 2.2.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232076) , some people had the same kind of problem :

> ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -
>   com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils$TemplateProcessingException:
>   freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated
>   to null or missing:
>   ==> manifestDir  [in template "root://activities/common/common_globals.xml.ftl" at line 26, column
>   39]

The problem was related to a **tmp** folder created on the **C** drive

> When I first installed Android SDK, I installed it to the C drive and
>   did some exercises inside ud851-Exercises-student there. Then, because
>   I ran out of space on the C drive, I uninstalled it from C and
>   installed it to D. Maybe I accidentally opened one of those projects
>   and that cause the Android Studio to create the tmp folder in C.

Deleting the **C:\tmp** folder solved the problem

> I was having the same issue...deleting tmp folder helped.

Some more information about the root cause :

> I realized this issue is because of the "buildDir" path in
>   build.gradle file in Udacity projects. See screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Berger, I was stuck here for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

1) Comment out the following code in gradle file (build.gradle)

buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}" ---comment this line

2) Use Sync Now at the top of the page to sync the project
3) Add the new Empty Activity (Child Activity)
4) Uncomment the lines you commented out in the gradle file
5) Sync the project again